# jquery plugin using Vimeo Froogaloop seeTo jumps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, vimeo, froogaloop

I'm working on an interactive transcript plugin using froogaloop as a dependecy. I have it almost exactly how I want it but I'm having an issue where when you click a sentence the video seekTo() goes to the right spot then jumps a few seconds forward. The jump seems to correlate to the time of the first span tag that is clicked.

Note: the clicking time bug doesn't happen if you press play first then click sentences. It does however reapear if you press pause and then click a sentence or click a sentance from a dead stop.

Hope this helps, I will be releasing this plugin once I can fix this error. I'm uis

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/r8FT2/1/

Comment: vimeo isn't opening at all, it says *Access to this site has been blocked as per Court Orders*

Comment: That link is working for me, how about http://aaron.ellissnyder.com/bootstrap/interactivetranscripts/index-plugin.html

Comment: I'm so sorry, just came to know that vimeo is blocked in india :(

Comment: Hi Aaron, were you able to fix this? I would really be interested in your plugin. It is exactly what I need.